# Read ASN Data as a JSON file Format

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to use python and scrape the website https://ipinfo.io/countries/ to get the data in the below format. This is nothing but the ASN Data.

The specific information below can be found in(https://ipinfo.io/AS3320)

```
{
  3320: {
     "country": "DE",
     "name": "Deutsche Telekom AG",
     "registry": "ripe",
     "num_ip_addresses": 34756096
 },
```

I have written a program that can get all the countries and then map it back to the ASN id  --> https://ipinfo.io/AS3320 However I am having difficulty to parse all the pages data using Beautiful soup.

```
import urllib.request
import bs4
import re
import json


url = 'https://ipinfo.io/countries'
SITE = 'https://ipinfo.io'

def url_to_soup(url):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    html = opener.open(req)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    return soup


def find_pages(page):
    pages = []
    for link in page.find_all(href=re.compile('/countries/')):
         pages.append(link.get('href'))
    return pages


def scrape_pages(links):
    mappings = {}

    print("Scraping Pages for ASN Data...")

    for link in links:
        country_page = url_to_soup(SITE + link)
        current_country = link.split('/')[2]
        for row in country_page.find_all('tr'):
            columns = row.find_all('td')
            if len(columns) > 0:
                #print(columns)
                current_asn = re.findall(r'\d+', columns[0].string)[0]
                #print("/AS"+current_asn)
                 #"Recursively I am generating the URL's using above "
                abc = url_to_soup(SITE + '/AS' + current_asn)
                print(abc.find_all('div')) 
                 #THe above code is where I am stuck with 
                 # How to get the country, name, registry, Ip_address
                #name = columns[1].string
                #print(name)
             """routes_v4 = columns[3].string
            routes_v6 = columns[5].string
            mappings[current_asn] = {'Country': current_country,
                                     'Name': name,
                                     'Registry': routes_v4,
                                     'num_ip_addresses': routes_v6}
return mappings"""


main_page = url_to_soup(url)
country_links = find_pages(main_page)
#print(country_links)
asn_mappings = scrape_pages(country_links)
#print(asn_mappings)
```

The result is a huge dump of HTML page consisting all the information, however I am not able to filter it as per the needs.

####################################################
Edit 1:
#####################################################

```
import urllib.request
import bs4
import re

url ='https://ipinfo.io/AS7018'
def url_to_soup(url):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
    html = opener.open(req)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    return soup


s = str(url_to_soup(url))
asn_code, name = re.search(r'<h3 class="font-semibold m-0 t-xs-24">(?P<ASN_CODE>AS\d+) (?P<NAME>[\w.\s]+)</h3>', s).groups()

print(asn_code)


country = re.search(r'.*href="/countries.*">(?P<COUNTRY>.*)?</a>',s).group("COUNTRY")
print(country)
registry = re.search(r'Registry.*?pb-md-1">(?P<REGISTRY>.*?)</p>',s, re.S).group("REGISTRY").strip()
print(registry)
# flag re.S make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline;
ip = re.search(r'IP Addresses.*?pb-md-1">(?P<IP>.*?)</p>',s, re.S).group("IP").strip()
print(ip)
```

Comment: I need help on regex to extract the Country, Name, registry and num_ip_address info. I am new to beautiful soup and not able to get the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

#### there should be 3-level page link in your needs

1 `https://ipinfo.io/countries/`  for `all countries`,

2 `https://ipinfo.io/countries/us` for `us all ASN`,

and 3 `https://ipinfo.io/AS26611` for `detail ASN data`.

It's seemed that step 3 missed in your codes, and if you get the page resource of detail ASN data page, you can use the regex below as reference ：

```py
s = """ your ASN detail data page """

asn_code, name = re.search(r'<h3 class="font-semibold m-0 t-xs-24">(?P<ASN_CODE>AS\d+) (?P<NAME>.*?)</h3>',s).groups()


country = re.search(r'.*href="/countries.*">(?P<COUNTRY>.*)?</a>',s).group("COUNTRY")

registry = re.search(r'Registry.*?pb-md-1">(?P<REGISTRY>.*?)</p>',s, re.S).group("REGISTRY").strip()

# flag re.S make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline;

ip = re.search(r'IP Addresses.*?pb-md-1">(?P<IP>.*?)</p>',s, re.S).group("IP").strip()
```

[see more regex flag, re.S](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=regex#re.S)

[more about re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=regex#re.search)

[more about regex syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=regex#regular-expression-syntax)

#### Besides, I highly recommend [`requests-html`](http://html.python-requests.org/) module both for efficiently request the page and parse the html (CSS selector and Xpath selector which are more efficient than regex).

hope it useful

Comment: Hi Jia, Thanks for contributing and helping. However I am getting error on my system for the line asn_code, name = re.search(r'<h3 class="font-semibold m-0 t-xs-24">(?P<ASN_CODE>AS\d+) (?P<NAME>[\w.\s]+)</h3>', s).group()

Comment: The error is Group is not available for None Type. I know that the regex might not be matching at some cases but not sure how to get rid of that

Comment: make sure that you get the page resource from detail page like `https://ipinfo.io/AS13489`

Comment: It seems that i will  get different result  from `https://ipinfo.io/AS7018` (page resource are not complete ) and `https://ipinfo.io/AS13489`, and now i am confused too.

Comment: Which system are you running the code on. I am getting errors for both the URL's. Can you please separate out the asn_code and name

Comment: AS13489 works, so i think it has nothing to do with regex syntax. I am now confusing why same request method get different page resource result.